# Are questions about Mathematica appropriate here?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

For example, I am trying to understand how Reap[] and Sow[] work in Mathematica. On the one hand, it's not really a question about mathematics per se. But on the other, it *is* a question that some of the math wizards here might be able to help me with.

SO, are questions about Mathematica appropriate here? And if not, is there a StackExchange site where they are on-topic?

Comment: There is [a proposal for a Mathematica-specific StackExchange site](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/15787/mathematica), but it does not yet exist.

Comment: See [answer](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3957/12400) for update on site status.

Answer (score 6):

The [*Mathematica* site](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/) mentioned in the comment above is (IMHO) the best source there is (better than *Mathematica* "support") for *Mathematica*-related questions.

Answer (score 5):

While we allow questions about mathematical software, the `Reap[]` and `Sow[]` functions are  *not* related to mathematics, but are *programming* tools for generating a list. Therefore, it is more suitable to ask on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com) for this question.